# ARM template ResourceID incorrect (comma added?)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to deploy Azure AppGateway from ARM template I built. However I keep running into errors:

```
The template variable 'appGatewayFrontendPort' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace. Current function arguments 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/,Logis-AppGW-UK/frontendPorts/appGatewayFrontendPort'.
```

For some strange reason my resourceID when I concat it, gets a comma added. I'm using similar resourceID calls in other objects and it goes through as expected. Relevant ARM template attached. Any help would be welcome. I have tried doing this with single variable, it ended up with same error. As you see, gatewaySubnetRef variable is referenced successfully with the same method, but I can't get it to work with appGatewayfrontendPort IP.

```
"variables": {
    "HUBVNET": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',concat('VNet-Logis-HUB-',parameters('RegionCode')))]",
    "LANVNet": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',concat('VNet-Logis-LAN-',parameters('RegionCode')))]",
    "DMZVnet": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',concat('VNet-Logis-DMZ-',parameters('RegionCode')))]",
    "StorageAccountName": "[toLower(concat('logis',parameters('RegionCode'),'storage'))]",
    "DMZServersDNS": "[split(parameters('DMZ DNS Server Address'),',')]",
    "LANServersDNS": "[split(parameters('LAN DNS Server Address'),',')]",
    "gatewaySubnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', concat('VNet-Logis-HUB-',parameters('RegionCode')), 'GatewaySubnet')]",
    "appGatewaySubnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', concat('VNet-Logis-HUB-',parameters('RegionCode')), 'AppGatewaySubnet')]",
    "appGatewayPublicIPRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', concat('AppGW-',parameters('RegionCode'),'-PublicIP'))]",
    "RecoveryServicesName": "[concat('BackupVault-Logis-',parameters('RegionCode'))]",
    "AppGwFrontendPortName": "[concat('Logis-AppGW-',parameters('RegionCode'),'/frontendPorts/appGatewayFrontendPort')]",
    "AppGwFrontendIP": "[concat('Logis-AppGW-',parameters('RegionCode'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/appGatewayFrontendIP')]",
    "appGatewayFrontendPort": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/', variables('AppGwFrontendPortName'))]",
    "appGatewayFrontendIP": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/', variables('AppGwFrontendIP'))]"
},
```

Comment: I think your missing a concat( on appGatewayFrontendPort and appGatewayFrontendIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

1) avoid using concat to create resourceIds, it's just harder, let the function do the work for you.

2) resourceIds require an equal number of segments and params.  Think of segments as the number of slashes in the type param.  Most resourceId function calls you see only have one, e.g.

```
    [resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'myVnet')]
```

But multi-segment ones are not uncommon:

```
    [resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'myVnet', 'firstSubnet')]
```

For your AppGateway front-end use:

```
    "appGatewayFrontendPort": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendPorts', concat('Logis-AppGW-',parameters('RegionCode')), 'appGatewayFrontEndPort')]"
```

And just get rid of the variable 'AppGwFrontendPortName'

A little more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too. Here more examples

Parameters

```
"authorizationRules": {
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
                "properties": {
                    "rights": [
                        "Listen",
                        "Manage",
                        "Send"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "SendListenAccess",
                "properties": {
                    "rights": [
                        "Listen",
                        "Send"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Output declaration

```
"eventHubAuthorizationRulesId": {
        "type": "array",
        "copy": {
            "count": "[length(parameters('authorizationRules'))]",
            "input": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/authorizationRules', parameters('namespace'), parameters('authorizationRules')[copyIndex()].name)]"
        }
    },
    "eventHubAuthorizationRulesId2": {
        "type": "array",
        "copy": {
            "count": "[length(parameters('authorizationRules'))]",
            "input": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', parameters('namespace'),parameters('eventHubName'), parameters('authorizationRules')[copyIndex()].name)]"
        }
    }
```

Prints:

```
"eventHubAuthorizationRulesId": {
    "type": "Array",
    "value": [
      "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/dummy-rg/providers/Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/namespaceEH-dummy-1/authorizationRules/RootManageSharedAccessKey",    
      "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/dummy-rg/providers/Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/namespaceEH-dummy-1/authorizationRules/SendListenAccess"
    ]
  },
  "eventHubAuthorizationRulesId2": {
    "type": "Array",
    "value": [
      "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/dummy-rg/providers/Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/namespaceEH-dummy-1/eventhubs/eventHub-dummy-1/authorizationRules/RootManageSharedAccessKey",
      "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/dummy-rg/providers/Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/namespaceEH-dummy-1/eventhubs/eventHub-dummy-1/authorizationRules/SendListenAccess"
    ]
  }
```